# Enable explorer dark mode in windows10

Tags: windows-10-v1803

I enabled dark mode in the settings however the explorer is not in dark mode. Is this not implemented yet? How do I get dark mode to work with explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dark mode for the explorer itself wasn't introduced until version ***1809***.  You have version ***1803***.